# Python : Remodelling a dataframe and regrouping data from a specific column with predefined rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Let's say that I have this dataframe with four columns : "Name", "Value", "Ccy" and "Group" :

```
import pandas as pd

Name = ['ID', 'Country', 'IBAN','Dan_Age', 'Dan_city', 'Dan_country', 'Dan_sex', 'Dan_Age', 'Dan_country','Dan_sex' , 'Dan_city','Dan_country' ]
Value = ['TAMARA_CO', 'GERMANY','FR56','18', 'Berlin', 'GER', 'M', '22', 'FRA', 'M', 'Madrid', 'ESP']
Ccy = ['','','','EUR','EUR','USD','USD','','CHF', '','DKN','']
Group = ['0','0','0','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':Name, 'Value' : Value, 'Ccy' : Ccy,'Group':Group})

print(df)
    
           Name      Value  Ccy Group
0            ID  TAMARA_CO          0
1       Country    GERMANY          0
2          IBAN       FR56          0
3       Dan_Age         18  EUR     1
4      Dan_city     Berlin  EUR     1
5   Dan_country        GER  USD     1
6       Dan_sex          M  USD     1
7       Dan_Age         22          2
8   Dan_country        FRA  CHF     2
9       Dan_sex          M          2
10     Dan_city     Madrid  DKN     3
11  Dan_country        ESP          3
```

1. I want to represent this data differently before saving it in a csv. I would like to group the duplicates in the column "Name" with the associates values in "Values" and "Ccy". I want that the data in the column "Value" and "Ccy" are stored in the row(index) defined by the column "Group". Like that I do not mixed the data.
2. Then if the name is in the "group" 0, it means that it is general data so I would like that the all the rows from this "Name" are filled with the same value.

So I would like to get this result :

```
   ID_Value  Country_Value  IBAN_Value  Dan_age Dan_age_Ccy  Dan_city_Value Dan_city_Ccy Dan_sex_Value
1  TAMARA    GER            FR56        18      EUR          Berlin         EUR          M
2  TAMARA    GER            FR56        22                                               M
3  TAMARA    GER            FR56                             Madrid         DKN
```

I can not find how to do the first part. With the code below, I do not get what I want evn if I remove the columns empty

```
g = df.groupby(['Name']).cumcount()

df = df.set_index([g,'Name']).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
```

Anyone can help me !

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following. See comments in code for each step:

```
s = df.loc[df['Group'] == '0', 'Name'].tolist() # this variable will be used later according to Condition 2
df['Name'] = pd.Categorical(df['Name'], categories=df['Name'].unique(), ordered=True) #this preserves order before pivoting
df = df.pivot(index='Group', columns='Name') #transforms long-to-wide per expected output
for col in df.columns:
    if col[1] in s: df[col] = df[col].shift().ffill() #Condition 2
df = df.iloc[1:].replace('',np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how='all').fillna('') #dataframe cleanup
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns.swaplevel()] #column name cleanup
df
Out[1]: 
        ID_Value Country_Value IBAN_Value Dan_Age_Value Dan_city_Value  \
Group                                                                    
1      TAMARA_CO       GERMANY       FR56            18         Berlin   
2      TAMARA_CO       GERMANY       FR56            22                  
3      TAMARA_CO       GERMANY       FR56                       Madrid   

      Dan_country_Value Dan_sex_Value Dan_Age_Ccy Dan_city_Ccy  \
Group                                                            
1                   GER             M         EUR          EUR   
2                   FRA             M                            
3                   ESP                                    DKN   

      Dan_country_Ccy Dan_sex_Ccy  
Group                              
1                 USD         USD  
2                 CHF              
3
```

From there, you can drop columns you don't want, change strings from "TAMARA_CO" to "TAMARA", "GERMANY" to "GER", use `reset_index(drop=True)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily with only 3 steps:

1. Split your data frame into 2 parts: the "general data" (which we want as a series) and the more specific data. Each data frame now contains the same kinds of information.
2. The key part of your problem: reorganizing the data. All you need is the [**pandas pivot**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function. It does exactly what you need!
3. Add the general information and the pivoted data back together.

```
# Split Data
general = df[df.Group == "0"].set_index("Name")["Value"].copy()
main_df = df[df.Group != "0"]

# Pivot Data
result = main_df.pivot(index="Group", columns=["Name"], 
                       values=["Value", "Ccy"]).fillna("")
result.columns = [f"{c[1]}_{c[0]}" for c in result.columns]

# Create a data frame that has an identical row for each group
general_df = pd.DataFrame([general]*3, index=result.index)
general_df.columns = [c + "_Value" for c in general_df.columns]

# Merge the data back together
result = general_df.merge(result, on="Group")
```

The result given above does not give the exact column order you want, so you'd have to specify that manually with

```
final_cols = ["ID_Value", "Country_Value", "IBAN_Value",
              "Dan_age_Value", "Dan_Age_Ccy", "Dan_city_Value",
              "Dan_city_Ccy", "Dan_sex_Value"]
result = result[final_cols]
```

Comment: You can maintain column order by declaring a column with `pd.Categorical` prior to pivotting.